# How can I stream music through VoiP? 

Tags: windows-7, audio, streaming, music, voip

What I want is: Stream a music through Teamspeak/Skype/Mumble... while I can talk also.
Using `Stereo mix` is not an option. If I use that, I can't speak, and everyone will just hear themselves.

OS: Windows 7 x64

(The question is rather brief. If you can extend it with anything, please do so.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) does the thing. It can mix several sources, so you can talk, and stream music at the same time. (And much, much more.) There is a free version available, the V3.